# Flask init-db no such command

Tags: python, flask

From yesterday I read a lot of topics about the famous error:

> "No such command init-db"

So, I followed the tutorial here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/database/

(I'm under Debian 9.6)

I do the following :

```
export FLASK_APP=webApp
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask init-db
```

I then tried:

```
python3 -m flask init-db
```

I also tried:

```
export FLASK_APP=webApp.py
```

But I still have the same error message.

Here is the tree of my project :

```
instance/
webApp/
├── auth.py
├── babel.cfg
├── dashboard.py
├── db.py
├── __init__.py
├── pdf.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── auth.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── db.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── pdf.cpython-35.pyc
│   └── ws.cpython-35.pyc
├── schema.sql
├── static
```

I didn't see what I've missed.

Comment: Please reveal a `db.py` content.

Comment: Also, do you somewhere import `db.py` file? You need to do that in order to register command via `Click`.

Comment: It is done via `from . import db` in that tutorial you used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the problem.
When I launched `flask --help`, I saw there was an import error of a module.   I just installed that module via `pip`, and it was okay.

Comment: what to install?

Comment: to me it was that I forgot to activate the virtualenv before running the command

Comment: Maybe you have to install Flask Migrate using pip first. Using pip command :
"pip install flask-migrate"

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue, and the problem was I had not imported migrate in my app. I solved the issue by adding these two statements to my file:
`from flask_migrate import Migrate` and `migrate = Migrate(app, db)` .
I saved the file, then ran the `flask db init` command again, and it worked!

Comment: These things should be mentioned clearly in docs. Very bad documentation. You saved my time

Answer (score 3):

First, be sure to activate your **virtual environment**.
If you are using a new terminal then run the command below:

```
export FLASK_APP="flaskr"
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

Run the flask app

```
flask run
```

After that run the DB command

```
flask init_db
```

You should see the *Database Initialized* message.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run `init-db` command, you first need to make sure you are outside the flaskr package (use pwd command if not sure) and at the same level as **venv** folder, then set the two below on the **terminal**:

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "flaskr"
$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
```

Then run:

`flask init-db`

Output: `Initialized the database.`

You don't need to install any extra packages if you follow the tutorial and execute the commands as they say.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the command I had to use was different, as seen from the flask --help output:

```
Commands:
  init.db
  routes   Show the routes for the app.
  run      Run a development server.
  shell    Run a shell in the app context.
```

So I had to use flask init.db for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help somebody and maybe made it more clear.

In my case I run the following command:

```
flask --app flask_app_directory_name db init
```

Here I mentioned where my app is by the option "--app":
flask_app_directory_name  - package of my app(or I think it could be a path to the file with the app).

Of course:

- I have installed Flask-Migrate;
- I have my flask app defined in **init**.py file of flask_app_directory_name package.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the  same problem !!! I did this and my problem got solved :

1.Create and activate virtual env for your project.

2.There seems to be issues with latest Flask-Migrate. So use this command `pip install --force-reinstall -v "Flask-Migrate==3.1.0"`

3.Problem solved run `flask db init`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem even though it worked the last time. 
I just ran the flask, then stopped it and tried to initialize the database and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You must set FLASK_APP correctly. It must match the directory name where the app factory lives.  In flaskr, this is in `flaskr/__init__.py`.  The factory is named create_app().

So if you rename `flaskr/`, you must set FLASK_APP to match.

Ref: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
flask init-db
```

I got this idea from the docs generated by the commands:

```
flask --help
```

[image: screenshot of output of above command]

Comment: How is this different from existing answers? SO platform's strength relies on voting on existing answers, rather submitting duplicates. Please edit if you have some unique, insightful, new content to add to your post. Duplicate "answers" run the risk of down votes, or even removal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create and activate the virtual environment using the venv command from the command prompt.
Those are the windows cmd commands:

```
cd path\pyproject
path\myproject> py -3 -m venv venv
path\myproject> venv\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

be careful that install flask_migrate in your env.
so in cmd:

1. create your env :

> cd myproject
> py -3 -m venv venv

2. activate your env:

> venv\Scripts\activate

3. install flask_migrate:

> pip install flask_migrate

Answer (score 0):

I had the error message. Here were what I did:

1. remove `'migrations'` folder if exists;
2. remove `'mydb.db'`.  (replace 'mydb.db' with yours)
3. run
   `flask --app flask_app_directory_name db init`

Answer (score 0):

i  think the answer lies in what you export

```
 export FLASK_APP=main( name of your python file where you are running the app)
export FLASK_ENV=development

flask db migrate -m "Your migration message"
```

also don't keep no using init again and again.
ideally have the init command  in your main application file
flask db upgrade

Answer (score 0):

So I had to specify the actual app name
$FLASK_APP=mypythonflaskapp.py db migrate -m

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could simply try using 
`flask init_db`

Note :- USE Underscore `_` instead of hyphen `-`

Cross verify it by checking if a **sqlite file is created in instance folder**

[It works like in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRLiL.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

I got the same problem. After executing `flask --help` or just `flask`, I realised the problem was caused by an import error and there was a typo in my FLASK_APP.

Correcting it made everything work again.